# How can I extract price of mobile phone from different ecommerce websites in php

Tags: php, html, css

How can I extract price of **mobile** phone from different ecommerce websites in php tell me code

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Firstly, this is not a tutorial website. Secondly, why will you add html and css tags? Finally, Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: downvoting.. smells like content stealing..

Answer (score 4):

You need to use API's of each and every eCommerce website you want to get prices from (IF THEY HAVE ONE) and you need to have permissions from those websites to copy prices. If you access prices without any of these, then Criminal penalties for copyright infringement include:

- A fine of not more than $500,000 or imprisonment for not more than five years, or both, for the first offense.
- A fine of not more than $1 million and imprisonment for not more than 10 years, or both, for repeated offenses.